# OpenGL Mesh Wrong Position

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, sdl, glew

I am trying to create a simple triangle mesh and after figuring out why I just got a blanc screen (for some reason the x64 configuration was giving me problems) I am facing a new issue:

The position of my vertices don't turn out to be how I want them. And I have no idea why.
What I should be getting is a triangle which looks about like this: 
[image]

What I am getting though is this:

[image]

I use GLEW 1.10.0 for loading OpenGL, GLM 0.9.5.4 for OpenGL math stuff and SDL 2.0.3 for window stuff. Everything running on Windows 8.1 in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with the latest Nvidia graphics drivers.

**Main.cpp:**

```
#include "Display.h"
#include "Shader.h"
#include "Mesh.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Display display(1200, 800, "Hello World");

    Vertex vertecies[] =
    {
        Vertex(vec3(-0.5, -0.5, 0)),
        Vertex(vec3(0.5, -0.5, 0)),
        Vertex(vec3(0, 0.5, 0))
    };

    Mesh mesh(vertecies, sizeof(vertecies) / sizeof(vertecies[0]));
    Shader shader(".\\res\\BasicShader");

    while (!display.IsClosed())
    {
        display.Clear(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        shader.Bind();
        mesh.Draw();

        display.Update();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Mesh.cpp:**

```
#include "Mesh.h"

Mesh::Mesh(Vertex* vertecies, unsigned int numVertecies)
{
    m_drawCount = numVertecies;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vertexArrayObject);
    glBindVertexArray(m_vertexArrayObject);

    glGenBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS, m_vertexArrayBuffers);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[POSITION_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertecies[0]) * numVertecies, vertecies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); 
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const void*)offsetof(Vertex, m_pos));

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

Mesh::~Mesh()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS, m_vertexArrayBuffers);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &m_vertexArrayObject);
}

void Mesh::Draw()
{
    glBindVertexArray(m_vertexArrayObject);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_drawCount);



    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

**Display.cpp:**

```
#include "Display.h"

Display::Display(int width, int height, string title)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    m_window = SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    m_glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);
    m_isClosed = false;

    GLenum status = glewInit();

    if (status != GLEW_OK)
        cerr << "Could not initialize GLEW!" << endl;
}

Display::~Display()
{
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(m_glContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Display::Clear(float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    glClearColor(r, g, b, a);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

bool Display::IsClosed()
{
    return m_isClosed;
}

void Display::Update()
{
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(m_window);

    SDL_Event e;

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))
    {
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
            m_isClosed = true;
    }
}
```

**Vertex Shader:**

```
#version 420 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
#version 420 core

out vec4 frag;

void main()
{
    frag = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**Vertex.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <glm\glm.hpp>

using namespace glm;

struct Vertex
{

public:

    Vertex(const vec3& pos);
    virtual ~Vertex();

    vec3 m_pos;

};
```

**Vertex.cpp:**

```
#include "Vertex.h"

Vertex::Vertex(const vec3& pos)
{
    m_pos = pos;
}

Vertex::~Vertex()
{
}
```

EDIT: Everything has now been fixed.

Comment: How is your Vertex class/struct layed out? Could you post its declaration?

Comment: @kolrabi Sure, just added Vertex.h and Vertex.cpp...

Comment: You shouldn't fix your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a data alignment issue where your Vertex class is being [padded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member). OpenGL would then interpret the padding bytes as valid data.

You can verify this by printing the result of `sizeof(Vertex)` which would be 8 (you mention a 64 platform) if it is indeed padded.

This tells OpenGL that there are floats tightly packed in memory, without padding:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

A better way of setting the vertex pointer would be:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const void*)offsetof(Vertex, m_pos));
```

This also enables you to easily add more attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! It finally works! The only thing is that `offsetof` takes 2 params, a type and a member of a type, so I just turned my Vertex class into a struct, made `m_pos` public and wrote `(const void*)offsetof(Vertex, m_pos)` instead of `(const void*)offsetof(Vertex.m_pos)`.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, that's a typo on my part.